# copy all files in SharePoint folder using microsoft Flow

Tags: office-365, 2016, flow

Is it possible to create a flow to copy all files in a SharePoint folder into another SharePoint folder?

I am able to use create file option after "`When a File is created`" trigger to copy the newly created file, But I want to copy all files in the folder

Can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

this can be achieved by utilizing one of the SharePoint templates available for Microsoft flow,

> Copy files from one SharePoint Online account or folder to another

For further details, please refer this link, [Copy files from one SharePoint Online account or folder to another](https://preview.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/c246fffdb0aa4578b8838f96950944f6/copy-files-from-one-sharepoint-online-account-or-folder-to-another/)

Answer (score 1):

You can copy SharePoint folders and subfolders in Microsoft Flow with the help of [Plumsail Actions](https://plumsail.com/actions/).

It has [Plumsail SP](https://plumsail.com/docs/actions/v1.x/flow/actions/sharepoint-processing.html) connector that provides a set of actions for SharePoint management, including copying folders cross-site.

Please review [this article describing how to do this](https://plumsail.com/docs/actions/v1.x/flow/how-tos/sharepoint/create-copy-move-remove-folders-cross-site.html).

Note: I'm a part of this product's development team.